# How to change svn url in svnsync?

Tags: svn, svnsync

How can I change (relocate) a subversion url that I entered when creating a mirror repository using "svnsync init" (example from `#https://whatever` to `svn://whatever`)?

tried to run svnsync init again with new url but

```
svnsync init file:///<path_to_mirror> http:///<new_url>
svnsync: Destination repository is already synchronizing from 'http:///<old_url>'
```

Comment: did you try using svnsync with the new url for subsequent sync's. My gut feel is it should work.

Comment: did try to call again svnsync init with new url but this doesn't work - svnsync says that the mirror repository is synced with "old" url

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The sync-from URL is stored as a revprop in the mirror repo. If on the machine with the mirror repository (my situation), use the **svnlook** tool to look and **svnadmin** to change:

```
user@q.r[~]$ svnlook pg --revprop -r0 /path/to/mirror/repo svn:sync-from-url
svn+ssh://svn.abc.com:1234/svn/foo
```

You will see the URL of the repo to which your mirror is currently syncing. In the above example, the master repo URL ends with ...**/foo**.  It may not have a newline at the end, so your shell prompt may follow. Now you need to get that into a file as svnadmin uses a file for input to change revprops.

```
user@q.r[~]$ svnlook pg --revprop -r0 /path/to/mirror/repo svn:sync-from-url > t.txt
```

Now edit **t.txt** to change the URL to the master repo. This can cause a newline to appear at the end of **t.txt** and result in obscure/meaningless error messages from svnsync. So get rid of it:

```
user@q.r[~]$ cat t.txt | tr -d '\n' > t2.txt
```

Note that we now have **t2.txt** which is the sanitized file. Then use **svnadmin** to change the revprop to the contents of the just-edited and sanitized file:

```
user@q.r[~]$ svnadmin setrevprop /path/to/mirror/repo -r0 svn:sync-from-url t2.txt
```

**Note that t2.txt is used not t.txt.** Finally, check your changes:

```
user@q.r[~]$ svnlook pg --revprop -r0 /path/to/mirror/repo svn:sync-from-url
svn+ssh://svn.def.com:5678/svn/foo
```

You should see your new repo URL immediately followed by the shell prompt, with no newline. In the above example the URL ends in foo and is immediately followed by the shell prompt user@q.r[~]$.

Comment: I followed this steps and get error when trying 

  svnsync sync /repo/path
  svnsync: Repository UUID '72fa8357-5795-f84a-b72d-10573eb4d6c2'  doesn't match expected UUID 'a3f6904a-36ca-4011-b160-aab731c98da0'

Comment: modify file db\revprops\0\0 and change svn:sync-from-uuid
property. now all ok

Answer (score 14):

If you use the account you use to run svnsync with you can simply use:

```
svn propset --revprop -r 0 svn:sync-from-url http://my.new/url url://to.my.repo
```

If you followed the instructions in the manual and added a pre-rev-props hook that denies everyone but the svnsync user to change the rev props this should work.

Answer (score 1):

[Svnsync](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svnsync.html) stores the remote repository URL in the revision properties of the first revision of the repository mirror. Thus, you can [view](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.propget.html) the currently configured repository URL on your local mirror like this:

```
$ svn pg --revprop -r0 svn:sync-from-url file:///path/to/svn-mirror
```

That means for changing the remote repository URL you just have to [change the revision property](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.propset.html). For example:

```
$ svn ps --revprop -r0 svn:sync-from-url https://svn.example.org/repo \
         file:///path/to/svn-mirror/
```

Example output:

```
property 'svn:sync-from-url' set on repository revision 0
```